# Designing your app to handle FIFO in Amazon SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, fifo, amazon-sqs

From the Amazon SQS FAQ page:

> Amazon SQS does not guarantee FIFO access to messages in Amazon
>   SQS queues, mainly because of the distributed nature of the Amazon
>   SQS. If you require specific message ordering, you should design your
>   application to handle it.

My question is - How does one design the application that way?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a message sequence counter while sending message. At receiving end, you can keep processing messages if sequence is right. In case an out of sequence message comes, wait till the right message comes (till then store messages in a list sorted by seq no.) and then process right sequence message and others which came in between.

Comment: That's it, in a nutshell. Messages that need to arrive in a specific order may not be a good candidate for SQS, or may be a sign of a conceptual deficiency.

Comment: Yups, that could work. But the code will get quite messy. Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: How'd you know the next seq counter to use in a code while composing the queue message, if its a api call sync. I didn't get that part. Plz.. - @pankajbatra

Comment: @pankajbatra - Also, if multiple jobs are listening to one specific queue(which is a common scenario in practical), How to handle that case in this way? I guess this will only work for single threaded queue listener job?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SQS has just gained [FIFO Queues with Exactly-Once Processing & Deduplication](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-amazon-simple-queue-service-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-delivery-deduplication/):

> Today we are making SQS even more powerful and flexible with support
>   for FIFO (first-in, first-out) queues. **We are rolling out this new
>   type of queue in two regions now**, and plan to make it available in
>   many others in early 2017.
>
> **These queues are designed to guarantee that messages are processed
>   exactly once, in the order that they are sent, and without duplicates**.
>   [...]
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

As emphasized, these new FIFO SQS queues will render any special application design for the use case at hand unnecessary, but are not yet available in all [SQS regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region) [initially only in US East (Ohio) and US West (Oregon)].

Answer (score 1):

Messages that need to arrive in a specific order may not be a good candidate for standard `SQS` queue. However you can set a message sequence counter while sending message and process message provided the sequence is right. In the event of not receiving the right sequenced message on the receiving side, you need to wait for the right message before processing it.[image]

On Nov 17th, 2016 FIFO Queue have been introduced in certain regions (US East (Ohio) and US West (Oregon)) which complements the standard queue. The order in which messages are sent and received is strictly preserved and a message is delivered once and remains available until a consumer processes and deletes it; duplicates are not introduced into the queue. FIFO queues use the same API actions as standard queues, and the mechanics for receiving and deleting messages and changing the visibility timeout are the same. However, when sending messages, you must specify a message group ID. enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly FIFO, but you can do something like this:

Creation of queues:

- Create N queues (say q1, q2, ..., qN)
- Have an upper limit in each queue (M number of messages per queue)

Inserting item in the queues:

- All jobs writing to the SQS will start from q1
- If q1 has M messages then move on to q2 and so on (after qN move to q1)

Picking item from the queues:

- All job reading from SQS will start picking item from q1
- If q1 is empty then move on to q2 and so on (after qN move to q1)

You need to make sure that draining one queue (reading out M messages) should take sufficiently lesser time than filling all the queues (pushing NxM messages). Which will ensure that batch of M messages will take priority over rest of the messages inserted in the queues. (First M messages In First M messages Out)